# Detect UIScreenEdgeGestureRecognizer and fail UIPanGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uigesturerecognizer

In my ViewController I have a `UIScreenEdgeGestureRecognizer` for switching views but also a `UITableView` with a custom `UITableViewCell`. In this custom `UITableViewCell` is a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` for swiping the cells.

I added `gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:` so both of the gestures are working and `gestureRecognizerShouldBegin` to prevent the conflict of vertical scrolling.

The question is, how can I give the `UIScreenEdgeGestureRecognizer` priority? When I swipe at the edge of the screen, I want to switch the views without panning the cells. I figured I should be using the delegate methods, but so far the more I read the more confused I'm getting.

Code in custom `UITableViewCell`:

```
override func viewDidload() {
    var recognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handlePan:")
    recognizer.delegate = self
    addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)
}

override func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    return true
}

override func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    if let panGesture = gestureRecognizer as? UIPanGestureRecognizer {
        let velocity = panGesture.velocityInView(superview!)
        if fabs(velocity.x) > fabs(velocity.y) { return true }
        return false
    }
    return false
}
```

ViewController:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    let rightScreenEdgeRecognizer = EdgePanGesture(target: self, action: "changeView:")
    rightScreenEdgeRecognizer.edges = .Right
    view.addGestureRecognizer(rightScreenEdgeRecognizer)
}
```

I also tried identifying the recognizers with:

```
gestureRecognizer.isKindOfClass(UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer)
```

and

```
gestureRecognizer as? UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer
```

But all were failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was looking at the right direction with `gestureRecognizer as? UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer` but instead of `gestureRecognizer` I should have used `otherGestureRecognizer`.

```
override func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRequireFailureOfGestureRecognizer otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    if let recognizer = otherGestureRecognizer as? UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer {
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```